# Apache Jena - get all resources with property

Tags: java, jena, ontology

I'm currently facing a problem and can't seem to find a solution in the net. In my project I have a RDF model with various smartphones, described like this:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="https://lukasgorny.pro/devices#GooglePixelXL2">
    <device-name>Google Pixel XL2</device-name>
    <screen-size>big</screen-size>
    <primary-camera-resolution>13</primary-camera-resolution>
</rdf:Description>
```

Is there a way I'm able to find all devices in Apache Jena with, f.e. "screen-size" property set as "big"? Regards, Lukas.

Answer (score 1):

```
Model m = RDFDataMgr.loadModel("phones.rdf", Lang.RDFXML);
m.listResourcesWithProperty(m.createProperty("screen-size"), m.createLiteral("big"))
        .forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

prints them to console

Comment: Sadly it does not work, returns 0 objects :(.

Edit: Okay, I've used beforehand created property and it works perfectly. Thanks!